# Passing a parameter to a FileField Storage's Save Method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-storage

So here is my situation. I have a model that I am saving, and it contains the following file:

```
file = models.FileField(storage=s3store, upload_to=custom_upload_to)
```

S3Store is a custom storage solution that I have implemented. Within that custom storage solution, I have a dictionary to all my different Amazon S3 Buckets [a dictionary with all S3BotoStorage connections]. Depending on who is uploading the file, I need to send it to it's appropriate S3BotoStorage, that is set to the appropriate bucket. I was wondering if it was possible to pass a parameter to my s3store.save() method from within my model save method?

I thought about simply appending the bucket_name to the filename, but appending & then removing would take too much calculation time no? (and memory).

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: No. Basic string manipulation of a file path will not take too much time or memory especially compared to pushing a file upload over HTTP.

Comment: So you suggest just appending / removing it from the path? (Makes my entire thing much easier now)...

Comment: I'm suggesting not throwing that out as a solution.